# Angular DataTables not showing any features or options

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, datatables

I am trying to use DataTables in Angular project but it just shows a basic table without any features or options

The package I am using

```
ng add angular-datatables
```

the HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="panel p-4">
        <h5 class="fw-bold">Destinations</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let destination of allDestinations">
                    <td>{{ destination.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ destination.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ destination.description }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

TS code

```
export class DestinationsComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  allDestinations: any[] = [];

  constructor(private _DestinationsService: DestinationsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.destinations();
  }

  destinations(): void {
    this._DestinationsService.destinations().subscribe((data) => {
      this.allDestinations = data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And I am already imported the DataTables module in the parent module of the component

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SetupRoutingModule } from './setup-routing.module';
import { DestinationsComponent } from './destinations/destinations.component';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DestinationsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SetupRoutingModule,
    DataTablesModule
  ]
})
export class SetupModule { }
```

This is the output I got

[image: Output]

Anyone please can help me fix this isssue?

Comment: Hello, don't forget to mention the exact library you use, not everyone knows avery datatable solution ;)

Comment: Have you implemented the following scripts in your angular.json?
`"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"`. You can see more within the official documentation. There are more libraries that need to be installed. [angular-datatables documentation](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts file, you need to have the dtOptions. Then you use in your component.

Example:

dtOptions: any = {};